# Table Coumn Issue in tailwindcss

Tags: css, html-table, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

If I include a name and navigate to the cursor using that name in inspection mode, the padding is displayed before the name rather than after it, as shown in the image.How to fix this issue
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptgHn.png)

```
<div class="relative overflow-x-auto">
    <table class="w-full text-sm text-left text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
        <thead class="text-xs text-gray-700 uppercase bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
                    <div class="flex items-center h-5">
                        <input id="candidates" name="candidates" type="checkbox"
                            class="w-4 h-4 text-indigo-600 border-gray-300 rounded focus:ring-indigo-500">
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
                    Name
                </th>
                <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
                    In Time
                </th>
                <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
                    Approved By
                </th>
                <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
                    Status
                </th>
                <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
                    Action
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="bg-white border-b dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
                <td scope="row" class="px-6 py-4">
                    <div class="flex items-center h-5">
                        <input id="candidates" name="candidates" type="checkbox"
                            class="w-4 h-4 text-indigo-600 border-gray-300 rounded focus:ring-indigo-500">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                    <div class="flex items-center gap-2">
                        <img class="w-10 h-10 rounded-full"
                            src="https://geeks-react.netlify.app/static/media/avatar-1.d2fd9642fd3628734b27.jpg"
                            alt="">
                        <a href="employee-detail.html"
                            class="inline-block font-semibold text-blue-600">Adolph Blaine Charles David Earl Frederick Gerald</a>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="px-6 py- whitespace-nowrap">
                    <span class="text-gray-600">
                        In : 02-06-2022 09:05 AM</span></br>
                    <span class="text-gray-600"> Out :
                        02-06-2022 05:07 PM</span>
                </td>
                <td class="px-6 py-4">
                    <span class="text-gray-600">
                        Prem</span>
                </td>
                <td class="px-6 py-4">
                    <div class="p-1 text-xs font-semibold text-center text-white bg-yellow-600 rounded-full">
                        Pending</div>                </td>
                       
            </tr>
            
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I want to show padding after the name ending. then only space is correctly shown for each column

Answer (score 0):

You could consider applying `width: max-content` to the flex `<div>`:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="relative overflow-x-auto">
  <table class="w-full text-sm text-left text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
    <thead class="text-xs text-gray-700 uppercase bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
          <div class="flex items-center h-5">
            <input id="candidates" name="candidates" type="checkbox" class="w-4 h-4 text-indigo-600 border-gray-300 rounded focus:ring-indigo-500">
          </div>
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
          Name
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
          In Time
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
          Approved By
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
          Status
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
          Action
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="bg-white border-b dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
        <td scope="row" class="px-6 py-4">
          <div class="flex items-center h-5">
            <input id="candidates" name="candidates" type="checkbox" class="w-4 h-4 text-indigo-600 border-gray-300 rounded focus:ring-indigo-500">
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class=" px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
          <div class="flex items-center gap-2 w-max">
            <img class="w-10 h-10 rounded-full" src="https://geeks-react.netlify.app/static/media/avatar-1.d2fd9642fd3628734b27.jpg" alt="">
            <a href="employee-detail.html" class="inline-block font-semibold text-blue-600">Adolph Blaine Charles David Earl Frederick Gerald</a>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="px-6 py- whitespace-nowrap">
          <span class="text-gray-600">
                        In : 02-06-2022 09:05 AM</span><br/>
          <span class="text-gray-600"> Out :
                        02-06-2022 05:07 PM</span>
        </td>
        <td class="px-6 py-4">
          <span class="text-gray-600">
                        Prem</span>
        </td>
        <td class="px-6 py-4">
          <div class="p-1 text-xs font-semibold text-center text-white bg-yellow-600 rounded-full">
            Pending</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```